Excel VBA using IF & OR not activating properly
Little head scratcher I've got
I have the below code to clear out entries from a table that don't contain two possible variables, however the 'clear contents' is activating with each row in the table. Is there something wrong with my syntax?
'   Loop through range
    For M2 = 2 To myLastRow2
        If Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(M2, "E").Value <> "Signalling" Or _
           Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(M2, "E").Value <> "Telecoms" Then _
                 Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(M2, "A").ClearContents
    Next M2 

I've tried a few variations on the code such as the below be neither work correctly
    For M2 = 2 To myLastRow2
        If Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(M2, "E").Value <> "Signalling" Or "Telecoms" Then _
                Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(M2, "A").ClearContents
    Next M2


The syntax is fine, but the effect is probably not what you intended: A<>x OR A<>y is always true, since it can't be both. You probably mean A<>x AND A<>y.

Just reverse the logic/condition in IF clause
Private Sub TestIF()
Dim m2 As Integer, MyLastRow2 As Integer
MyLastRow2 = 7
For m2 = 2 To MyLastRow2
        If Not (Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(m2, "E").Value = "Signalling" Or _
            Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(m2, "E").Value = "Telecoms") Then
                 Worksheets("CRE ATW").Cells(m2, "A").ClearContents
        End If
Next m2
End Sub


Thank you.

Using Select Case:
For M2 = 2 To myLastRow2
    With Worksheets("CRE ATW").Rows(M2)
        Select Case .Columns("E").Value
            Case "Signalling", "Telecoms" 'do nothing
            Case Else
                .Columns("A").ClearContents
        End Select
    End With
Next M2 

